# Using cloudflare for github pages

Tags: github

Don't get me wrong, GitHub Pages is amazing. It's just that I want some of the features of cloudflare offers. Such as caching. Caching on GitHub pages is only 10 minutes. I want more cache time, at least a week. Also, using a cdn would speed up loading for my website.

So I am trying to use cloudflare on GitHub Pages

I have found numerous videos and tutorials on have to host websites from GitHub Pages through cloudflare. I want to keep my GitHub url but go through the cloudflare system. How can I do this? In your answer, can you also give me a explanation of what to enter when setting up DNS in cloudflare? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this keeping your GitHub urls. You would need changing their DNS pointing to CloudFlare, ... which won't be doable.